# Is there a way to get notified if the session recycles WHILE processing an asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an asp.net application that utilizes long polling.  So, a typical call to the aspx page can take 30 seconds or more.

I've noticed, sometimes in wait-state the session recycles (for known reasons) and the Session[] object is wiped.  At this point, I would like to be able to cut the wait short and signal the aspx page to complete and let the browser attempt to reconnect and set up a new valid session.

is there a "Session Got Recycled" event I can listen to?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Session_End` in the `global.asax`:

```
protected void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs E) {
    // Clean up session resources
}
```

Comment: Note that this wont work if session is stored in State Server or SQL Server.

Comment: Hmm I know than one.  I guess I'd have to get the page class to listen for events on a third object (application instance) and have Session_End() signal it.  Would that work? since it runs only in global.asax http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatemodule.end.aspx